# How to create a weighted vertices in Cypher for Graph Database?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, pagerank

I am trying to understand which user has the most influence based on the amount of the reviews that was done by the user, i user the following code to project my graph

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher(
            'last_try',
            'match (n) WHERE (n:USER) OR (n:REVIEWS) return id(n) AS id',
            'MATCH (u:USER)<-[:POSTED]-(r:REVIEWS)<-[:REVIEWED]-(b:BEERS)
            RETURN id(u) AS source, id(b) AS target, count(distinct r) as weight'
            )
```

I am trying to create a weight variable but when i run it through the algorithm, i do not receive anything, or ai receive static values

```
CALL gds.pageRank.stream('last_try', {relationshipWeightProperty:'weight'})
            YIELD nodeId, score
            RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).username AS name, score
            ORDER BY score desc
            limit 5
```

Also here is the algorithm that i am trying to run but unsuccessfully i can not get a logic result

I tried to implement different solutions, but i did not manage to find any solution, i tried to count the attributes of the reviews  made by those users, and the hard part is to understand what to attribute to the weight parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the query to put the number of reviews done by that user. It will put a new property 'weight' on REVIEWS based on the number of times that user posted a review on any beer.

```
MATCH (u:USER)
WITH u
MATCH (u)<-[p:POSTED]-(r:REVIEWS)<-[rw:REVIEWED]-(b:BEERS)
WITH u, count(r) as cnt, collect(distinct r) as reviews
UNWIND reviews as r
SET r.weight =  cnt
```

For example:

```
╒════════════════════════════════╕
│"review"                        │
╞════════════════════════════════╡
│{"review":"review11","weight":2}│
├────────────────────────────────┤
│{"review":"review12","weight":2}│
├────────────────────────────────┤
│{"review":"review21","weight":1}│
├────────────────────────────────┤
│{"review":"review32","weight":1}│
└────────────────────────────────┘
```